# How to create a Java class with built-in variables

Tags: java, class

I didn't know how to word the title well, but here is my question:
I am making a maze game in Java, and I would like to make a class so I can set blocks easily:

`addBlock(32, 32)`

The first and second numbers are the x and y coordinates of where the block should be placed.
I am a beginner at Java, and have come from Python.

Comment: how would you do this in Python?

Comment: Define a class `Block` and create a constructor that takes the two parameters...

Comment: I don't understand, do you already have the logic for this `addBlock` class but don't know how to construct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a basic pojo like this:

```
    public class Block {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Block(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

    }
```

You can then create a `Maze` class for example:

```
    public class Maze {

        public void addBlock(Block block) {
            // your logic here
        }

    }
```

The data structure to use for storing `Block` objects depends of the situation. I recommend a `HashMap` with a `String` key based on coordinates (if it has irregular shape) or an array/`List`.

`HashMap` version:

```
private Map<String, Block> blocks; // ...

public void addBlock(Block block) {
    blocks.put(block.getX()+","+block.getY(), block);
}
```

array version:

```
private Block[][] blocks; // ...

public void addBlock(Block block) {
    blocks[block.getX()][block.getY()] = block;
}
```

You can see that the advantage of the `HashMap` version is that it is dynamic. You have to initialize an array with default values.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want some high-incapsulation solutions?

```
public class Maze {
    private class Block {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Block(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    private List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();

    public Maze addBlock(int x, int y) {
        this.blocks.add(new Block(x, y));
        return this;
    }
}
```